# Porcelain Mark Translation?

Tags: translation, mandarin

I've recently come in acquisition of some artifacts and I'm looking to learn more about their origin and history. I thought I'd start with the maker's mark. If anyone could help me out with translating this image that would be awesome!

[image: Porcelain Mark]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 大明宣德年制
>
> This is a product made in the series of years named 'Xuande' of the Ming Dynasty.（Around 1400）

Since 'Xuande''s were among the 1st period in the history to mark porcelain with marks, and also the first several years when the Chinese people developped an aesthetism for Qinghua （blue-and-white）, their values are normally extremely high and particularly preferred by forgers.

PS. Even forgers in the history loved to fabricate porcelain with 大明宣德.

Comment: +1 for the forgery caveat. I guess authentic ones wouldn't need to bear such a claim.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow Authentic ones do have such a claim. An expert, [孙瀛洲](http://baike.baidu.com/view/250813.htm) said, "宣德款识遍器身", which suggests the inscription is a convention. However forgeries of year of 宣德 have had a somehow long history: there exist some in 嘉靖 and 万历 in Ming Dynasty, and even some in Qing Dynasty. So currently even some forgeries are deemed as treasures. Anyway, be highly alert to such things, too many counterfeits!

Comment: @Stan, I didn't know that. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow It depends. Sometimes the fake ones are also very valuable because they are fabricated by some famous craftsman...And as I have said, some forgeries are also really old.